# The server tag is not well formed. LinkButton inside repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater, asplinkbutton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server" CssClass="csstab" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'
OnClientClick="return ShowInEditMode('<%#Eval("ID") %>')"></asp:LinkButton>
```

I want to call the OnClientClick to call javascript method with passing a parameter. I am getting Server Tag is not well formed error. I tried changing double quotes to single quote etc, still the same issue.

The server tag is not well formed. LinkButton inside repeater

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OnClientClick event is having some wrong things.

use OnClientClick in the following way

```
OnClientClick='<%# string.Format("javascript:return ShowInEditMode({0})", Eval("ID"))%>'
```

Comment: it should call. just put a debugger in javascript function and while running the page, click that button which is calling this method and check that Debugger is called or Not ?

Comment: this solution is not gona work because the return ShowInEditMode({0}) needs an other single quote :) around {0} it should be like ' string.Format("javascript:return ShowInEditMode('{0}')", Eval("ID")) which will give you the same error

Comment: i am using this code in almost 25 pages on my application with single or multiple parameters and i am not getting any error.

Comment: @KamranAjmal , the output I am getting is the same as Kiarash: e.g. return ShowInEditMode(123). It should be ShowInEditMode('123'). How do we do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well use this in html bit

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server" CssClass="csstab" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>' OnClientClick='<%#CreateShowInEditModeMethod(Eval("ID")) %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then define this in your code behind

```
 protected string CreateShowInEditModeMethod(string str)
 {
        return String.Format("return ShowInEditMode('{0}');", str);
 }
```

let me know if did not solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace external double quotes with single and & Eval quotes to double will work.

change `onClientClick` to:

```
OnClientClick='return ShowInEditMode("<%#Eval("ID") %>")'
```